# JBoss EJB Client using HTTP Proxy

Tags: java, jboss, proxy, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to make a EJB invocation using jboss-remoting to a Wildfly 8.2.1 server that can be accessed only via HTTP Proxy.

It fails like:

```
Feb 23, 2016 2:50:34 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 2.0.1.Final
Feb 23, 2016 2:50:34 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
Feb 23, 2016 2:50:34 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
Feb 23, 2016 2:50:34 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.7.Final
Feb 23, 2016 2:50:40 PM     org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to 192.x.y.z:443
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
```

It tried to set Java System Props, like below, but no use:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=web-proxy.yyy.xxx.net
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=web-proxy.yyy.xxx.net
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-DproxySet=true
```

We are using PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration, but I can't find a "remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.*" like property for setting proxies.

Current config:

```
("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "true");
("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS", "true")
("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_PROTOCOL", "TLS")
("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL", "600000")
("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false")
("remote.connections","default")
("remote.connection.default.host", host)
("remote.connection.default.port", port)
("remote.connection.default.protocol", protocol)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution is to uninstall the Antivirus software. The Antivirus, Bitdefender, blocked the communication of Wildfly.

Comment: Actually I found out that it really doesn't support HTTP Proxy's using jboss-remoting.

Answer (score 0):

EJB Client support for forward HTTP proxy is requested here: [EJB-Client cannot connect by HTTP-proxy](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/XNIO-274). It seems to be a problem with XNIO (low-level I/O library used by JBoss Remoting) rather then EJB client itself.